# Why is the google map displaying further down the page & not where the grey load box is?

Tags: jquery, google-maps

Why is the google map displaying further down the page, & not where the grey load box is? Is this a jquery loading issue. I tried including jquery in the WP header, & this doesn't seem to have solved it.

I'm using a wordpress plugin to display the map (which I know works fine) in a wordpress site. I have included it here rather than the wp section, as this is probably a jquery load issue. Basically the google map displays in the footer area of the website, rather than at the top over the grey box loading area.

I can't include an image of the issue, as my reputation is not above 10

Here is the php, i'm using to include the jquery in the functions.php of my wp theme:

```
function insert_jquery(){
wp_enqueue_script('jquery', false, array(), false, false);
}
add_filter('wp_enqueue_scripts','insert_jquery',1);
```

Comment: An image wouldn't help much anyway. You can't troubleshoot layout issues from an image. Use browser css inspector to look for clues and see if any errors are thrown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Maps doesn't actually use jQuery, so it seems unlikely that it's the problem.

It's probably some kind of CSS issue, I'd look down that avenue.